# How do I make a diagram like this in LaTeX? Thanks!

Tags: diagrams

[image]

How to draw this comutative diagrams in LaTeX

Answer (score 4):

Check the Matrix library example here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/commutative-diagram-tikz/

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
{
 A & B \\
 A/ker f & f(A) \\};
   \path[-stealth]
(m-1-1) edge node [left] {$p_{ker f}$} (m-2-1)
        edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-2) edge node [right] {$i$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-1) edge [dashed] node [above] {$\bar{f}$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a job for `tikz-cd`. This is a quick proposal

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,"f"]\arrow{d}[left]{p_{\ker f}} & B \\
A/\ker f \arrow[r,"\bar{f}",dashed] & f(A) \arrow{u}[right]{i}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: instead `dashrightarrow` is sufficient `dashed`.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for that. I was just searching in the manual about a dashed arrow, and came to `dashrightarrow`. I wasn't thinking probably